# Calculate the y coordinate of a point of a elliptic curve with SAGE?

Tags: sage, elliptic-curve

I defined with SAGE:

```
p=(10^34+1000).next_prime()
E=EllipticCurve(GF(p),[0,57])
```

My problem is:

I know the x coordinate of a P of the Elliptic Curve 1407284663933896236729058440000

**How can I calculate the y coordinate with SAGE?. Any function?**

```
E([1407284663933896236729058440000, ??????])
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
sage: E.lift_x(1407284663933896236729058440000)

(1407284663933896236729058440000 : 4215171991512676773155222850458328 : 1)
```

I suggest that you read the Sage reference manual before asking more such questions here.

Comment: Thank you very much, i read the SAGE manual but i don't find that function. Tahnk you very much and sorry for the inconveniece.

Comment: this response saved me a lot of time so thanks for asking and answering it here :)

Comment: And here is the [link to the documentation](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/arithmetic_curves/sage/schemes/elliptic_curves/ell_generic.html#sage.schemes.elliptic_curves.ell_generic.EllipticCurve_generic.lift_x).